# Changing java applet background with javascript

Tags: java, javascript, colors, applet

I have a java applet with a Methods inherited from class java.awt.Component. I need to change the color of the background of the applet in javascript function but using

```
my_selected_applet.setBackground('FFFFFF');
```

is not working, Firebug complain about :

```
uncaught exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
No method found matching name setBackground and arguments [java.lang.String]
```

As the method exist, i think it is the argument that is not working.

Comment: would be helpful if you can post full method or full code if not too long

Comment: 1998 called it wanted its post back

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use this:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

my_selected_applet.setBackground(Color.white);
```

or in html page:

You can set the background color of an applet in the following manner:

```
<applet code="MyApplet.class" width="100" height="100">
<param name="background-color" value="#ffffff">
<param name="foreground-color" value="#000000">
</applet>
```

Comment: don't see why it needs to be done in javascript. will need to see full code. why not do it in the applet? especially when .setBackground is a java function.

Comment: None of us know the reasons for his requirements, but I assume that the user already knows how to do this inside of the applet since the solution for this is trivial. So regardless of his rationale, your answer doesn't answer his direct question. Also, if his Applet is written in Swing, your code wouldn't work since its the contentPane that would need to have its background color changed and not the applet itself. All we can do is request more information from the original poster and hope that he responds. Unless someone knows the solution off hand.

Comment: ah this goes back to the fact that you'd rather point fingers than answer the question. why not answer it then? I don't see why he's using a java command in javascript anyway.

Comment: I'm not answering it because I simply don't know the solution. I don't code JavaScript.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm not sure which puzzles me more. This question or the fact that a Java programmer doesn't know javascript. Oh well

Comment: Arpit's solution looks promising to me, so let's see whether it leads to a solution. I don't think that the question is too far fetched and can see a possible need for it.

Comment: Again, I don't code JavaScript, but it's certainly not Java since it uses var type and single quotes for String. And on review of the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html), it does in fact look to be valid JavaScript code for interaction with Java applets, yes.

Comment: The fact is the event that i want to trigger the change of the applet background is from javascript. So i need javascript code to control the background property of the applet. I will try your solutions and post later.

Answer (score 0):

[setBackground](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBackground%28java.awt.Color%29)

you need to pass the color object in the function.

so just create a color object `var color = new Color('CC9933');`

and then try `setBackground(color)`

you have to read this for more info : [Applet methods from javascript](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html)